# Route traffic to multiple node servers based on a condition

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, load-balancing, multiplayer

I'm coding an online multiplayer game using nodejs and HTML5 and I'm at the point where I would like to have multiple maps for people to play on, but I'm having a scaling issue. The server I'm running this on isn't able to support the game loops for more than a few maps on its own, and even though it has 4 cores I can only utilize one with a single node process.

I'd like to be able to scale this to not even necessarily be limited to a single server. I'd like to be able to start up a node process for each map in the game, then have a master process that looks up what map a player is in and passes their connection to the correct sub process for handling, updating with game information, etc.

I've found a few ways to use a proxy like nginx or the built in node clusters to load balance but from what I can tell the examples I've seen just give a connection to whatever the next available process is, and I need to hand them out specifically. Is there some way for me to route a connection to a node process based on a condition like that? I'm using Express to serve my static content and socket.io for client to server communication currently. The information for what map the player is in will be in MongoDB along with the rest of the player data, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Of course you could make nginx to proxy traffic to different nodes based on some conditions. But some conditions are easier to check than others. Simplest way is to have different urls for different maps

Comment: I wasn't sure if just doing different urls for different maps would be a good way to go since that would open up the problem of a player going to a url for a map they aren't actually in. I was hoping for some kind of solution that would be invisible to the client.

Comment: There should be a little such players, so you could easily redirect them to appropriate url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to adress your problem, here are two suggestions based on your description.

1 - Use a router server which will dispatch players queries to "Area servers" : in this topology all clients queries will arrive to your route server, the server tag each query with a unique id and dispatch it to the right area server, the area server handle the query and sendit back to the route server which will recognize it from the unique tag and send back the response to the client.

this solution will dispatch the CPU/memory load but not the bandwidth !

2 - Use an authentication server which redirect client to the servers with less load : in this case, you'll have multiple identical servers and one authentication server, when a client authenticate, send the url and an auth token of available server to the client and an authentication ticket to the server.
the client then connect to the server which will recognize using the auth toekn/auth ticket.

this solution will dispatch all CPU/Memory/Bandwidth, but might not be suited to all games since you can be sent to different server each connection and you'll not see the players in the same area if you are not on the same server.

those are only two simple suggestions, you can mix the two approaches or add other stuff (for example inter-communication area servers etc) which will solve the mensioned issues but will add complexity.

Comment: I'm experimenting with a solution similar to number 1 that you proposed where I have a master that forwards packet data to worker processes in a cluster, but you're right bandwidth is still an issue. Solution 2 seems optimal, I'll need to go back and look more at socket.io on the client to try to implement that without needing to refresh the page.

Comment: if you are working with websockets, I made an RPC library which will make you job much easier :)
take a look at http://eureca.io/ , it provide an RPC layer on top of your favorite websocket library (including socket.io) ...and there is also an experimental WebRTC support which help a lot in multiplayer stuff and has less bandwidth consumption ...
hope it can help

Comment: @MikeBall I know it's been a while since you asked this, but I had a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020580/how-to-route-a-user-to-a-specific-machine-using-nginx and was wondering what approach you ended up going with for this problem.